# font-face: Special fonts for Safari iOS

Tags: css, safari

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Caecilia";
        src: url("Assets/CaeciliaLTStd-Bold.ttf"), format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    h1 { color:#23445f; font-family:Caecilia;}
```

This sampel code works in Chrome, but not in Safari(both regular and iOS version). Is there a special fix for Safari?

Comment: You'll need an SVG file for Safari... Have a look at Font Squirrel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the font links available in different formats from where you got them? If so, then try the following.

```
   @font-face {
    font-family: "Caecilia";
    src: url("Assets/CaeciliaLTStd-Bold.eot") format('embedded-opentype'), /* EDIT correction on this line */
    url('Assets/CaeciliaLTStd-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
    url('Assets/CaeciliaLTStd-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('Assets/CaeciliaLTStd-Bold.svg#') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style:normal;
  }
```

**EDIT: EDIT:** I am sorry. I had `ttf` instead of `eot` in the first declration for embedded-opentype. Give this a try

Comment: This works for the desktop version of Safari but not for the mobile one.

Comment: I had a mistake there when i entered `ttf` instead of `eot` for embedded-opentype. Try it now.

Comment: Thx, it works now. But only if I open the site trough Safari. I've created an app with a webview and for some reason it doesn't work there.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the appropriate permissions, you can try using Font Squirrel to generate all the appropriate fonts and CSS necessary for what you're trying to accomplish:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator